# How to get specific elements of array using filter in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

I am trying to get a certain value; for example, if I got ‘works1’ as this works_id, I want to get element which contains ‘works1’ as works_id

```
 export default{
images: [{ works_id:'works1', 
        mother: require('@/assets/works/works1-0.png'), 
        children: [require('@/assets/works/works1-1.png')
        , require('@/assets/works/works1-2.png'), require('@/assets/works/works1-3.png'), require('@/assets/works/works1-4.png')]},
        { works_id:'works2',
        mother: require('@/assets/works/works2-0.png'), 
        children: [require('@/assets/works/works2-1.png')
        , require('@/assets/works/works2-2.png'), require('@/assets/works/works2-3.png'), require('@/assets/works/works2-4.png'), require('@/assets/works/works2-5.png')]}




]
```

}

```
  <template>
 <div class="deWorks">
    <div>
        <img :src="getWorksImgs.mother">
    </div>
    <div v-for="(Img , index) in getWorksImgs.children" :key="index">
        <img :src="Img">
    </div>
 </div>
  </template>

<script>
import StoreWorks from '@/store/works'

export default {
data(){
    return {
        worksImgs : StoreWorks.images,
        works_id: this.$route.params.works_id
    }   
},
    computed: {
    getWorksImgs(){
        let worksImgs = this.worksImgs
        // let works_id1 = this.$route.params.works_id
        worksImgs= worksImgs.filter(w => w.works_id === this.works_id )

        return worksImgs

    }
}
</script>
```

I have cross-posted the code here:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/filter-help-trying-to-get-specific-elements-of-array-using-filter/54597

Comment: Please add a link to your duplicate on the other site to point back here, so that if you get an answer here first, time of readers on the other one will not be wasted on duplicate effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is throwing an error because `getWorksImgs()` returns an array, not an object.

```
<div>
    <img :src="getWorksImgs.mother">
</div>
```

This next part will also throw an error due to the same reason above

```
<div v-for="(Img , index) in getWorksImgs.children" :key="index">
    <img :src="Img">
</div>
```

You'll want to move the for loop on your top div

```
 <div class="deWorks" v-for="(o, i) in getWorksImgs" :key="i">
    <div>
        <img :src="o.mother">
    </div>
    <div v-for="(Img , index) in o.children" :key="index">
        <img :src="Img">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The getWorkImgs() computed value will return an array because of the filter.

```
    computed: {
      getWorksImgs() {
        return this.worksImgs.filter( w => w.works_id === this.works_id);
      }
    }
```

This should work:

```
    <template>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="deWorks" v-for="(o, i) in getWorksImgs" :key="i">
          <div>
            <img :src="o.mother">
          </div>
          <div v-for="(Img , index) in o.children" :key="index">
            <img :src="Img">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import StoreWorks from '@/store/works'

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          worksImgs: StoreWorks.images,
          works_id: this.$route.params.works_id
        }
      },
      computed: {
        getWorksImgs() {
          return this.worksImgs.filter( w => w.works_id === this.works_id);
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```